# chrome.cookies is not returning a cookie

Tags: cookies, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am currently porting a Chrome extension to Edge extension.

I have set "cookies" and host permissions in `manifest.json` file.

I even used details like "url", "name" and "domain" to get the cookie, but nothing works.

Is this a new bug introduced in the recent anniversary update from Microsoft?

**Edited**
This is the code syntax i am using,

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({url : "siteUrl", domain : "siteDomain", name : "ticketName"}, 
function(cookies) 
{ 
    console.error(cookies.length); 
});
```

Comment: It would help make the question easier to answer if you could share enough code to to make the problem minimally reproducible.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide more details about your code, the previous post cannot help us clarify it's a bug or code issue.

Comment: @HaibaraAi i have added the code syntax, i cannot reveal the url, domain and name i use since it is against my company policy.